# Android Global Progress Dialog

Tags: android, asynchronous

I have an `AsyncTask` class that handles all networking calls for my app. I also have a `Globals` class that holds a progress dialog. Now, what I want is for there to only be one progress dialog at a time; this is fairly simple. The `Globals` class initializes the dialog, and each time it is used by the `AsyncTask`, only the message is changed. My issue is determining when to dismiss it. If I use `p.dismiss()` at the end of `onPostExecute()`, then the progress bar will go away until the next `AsyncTask` runs, which is not what I want. However, if I don't include the line there, then the progress dialog will stay up indefinitely. I guess what I'm trying to find is a way to see if all `AsyncTasks` have finished running. By doing this, then that one global progressdialog will be able to close without looking wonky.

Chaining together all the `AsyncTasks` is not an option (e.g. having the first one execute the second in its `onPostExecute()`).

Also note that there could be anywhere between one and five `AsyncTasks` running at the same time.

How can I determine if every `AsyncTask` is complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could keep track of how many you are starting and create a callback to the class every time a task finishes, then when the returned count matches the start count you know all the tasks are done.

there really is no way to know when see what tasks are running without doing some thing like that.

there is a [getStatus](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#getStatus%28%29) but you would have to keep polling for the status to see if the individual task is done or not

Comment: Ah. I was afraid it would come to that. Oh well. Thank you for your help.

aand the site tells me I have to wait for 4 minutes to give you the best answer.

Comment: You wouldn't need to poll-  in the onPostExecute of each task, check to see if all the other tasks are in finished.  If so, then all of them are finished.  If not, then not all of them are finished.  So all you need to do is keep a list of tasks that were started.  But for his use, a simple variable that gets incremented in onPreExecute of each task and decremented in onPostExecute of each class and dismiss the dialgo when it hits 0.

Comment: Gabe, that's actually a much simpler method than what I had thought of. Thank you; it's very useful :)

Comment: @GabeSechan right thats is what I was getting at, it was just the first thing that came to my head.